# Magento 2.0.14 and 2.1.7 security update - possible issues?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, security, patches

Reference: [Magento 2.0.14 and 2.1.7 security update](https://magento.com/security/patches/magento-2014-and-217-security-update?mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiWWpRNE5tUTRNVE5pTmpaaSIsInQiOiJJajRqM0UremlDekJ5aUxrSlZKQkJ4VzlETnFWREllY2dGOG02Y1MwS283eG5cL0VFSXkrcjhBTWhYeDlObk5hU00wM2dkbk9HaUZtdDJFb1Qya0FwRkJRb0Z5R00yQm1qTFN0NWlZMnpjanZENnM5allsZFNLZ2NLVVdZdmJxT1YifQ%3D%3D)

How can I apply the 15 patches in older versions like 2.0.13 or 2.1.6?

What are the possible issues?

Comment: There are not 15 patches available for Magneto 2.x